# Can't remove group after upgrading to gitlab 6.0

Tags: configuration, gitlab, rhel, usergroups

I'm running gitlab on RHEL 6, 5.4 was running fine for the past month or so -- I upgraded to 6.0 and things appeared ok, but users can no longer remove their groups from the groups settings. I get a 500 error.

I thought the error was part of the upgrade process, so deployed 6.0 as a new install, and everything works fine except for users can not remove groups from the groups settings. Administrators can remove groups via the admin panel, but not the groups settings.

odd thing, the logs look exactly the same, same auth token, same GET request. Beyond reading the log files, i'm not sure where to start debugging this issue. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe related is the following issue on the issue tracker: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4870

Comment: It was. And promptly fixed by randx. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/1ac6078b051da30d26185ba95933d21f30bb73fc Thanks for the heads ups.